# Does using Transmuted Spell metamagic change Wall of Fire's line of sight mechanics

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic, line-of-sight

How does this affect Wall of Fire mechanically in terms of line of sight if it took on an element other than fire. And how is this supposed to make sense thematically.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 8):

#### The Transmuted Spell Metamagic does *nothing* but change the damage type

That is the only thing this Metamagic does and all the other effects of the spell do not change. So the *wall of fire* is still a wall of fire and is still opaque, it just, through the power of magic, now deals a different type of damage.

When Transmuted Spell is used the *only* thing that changes is the damage type, if something else were to change, the feature would say so.

Comment: The fire is now presumably temperate but loud, though I'm sure if it's worth mentioning that there isn't a provision for the fire now being audible in any way (despite dealing thunder damage). Transmuted spell seems to leave a lot of narrative/description on the table, which may be worth talking with your table about before choosing the metamagic to make sure you make it work with your table's style of play.